# $L_p$ norm not subadditive for $0<p<1$ when endowed on $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#When_0_.3C_p_.3C_1), the $L_p$-norm is not subadditive when $p\in(0,1)$. 
How can I show that the map $n_p(f)=(\int_0^1|f(x)|^p~\mathrm{d}x)^{2p}$ is not subadditive for $f\in C[0,1]$ for $0<p<1$?

Comment: Is the power of the integral purposely $2p$ or should it be $\frac{1}{p}$?

Answer (score 3):

You can show this by  just posing an counterexample,for instance,take $f(x)=x$and $g(x)=1-x$. For $p=\frac{1}{2}$,then one has $$\left(\int_{0}^{1}|f+g|^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\right)^2=1>\frac{8}{9}=\left(\int_{0}^{1}|f|^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\right)^2+\left(\int_{0}^{1}|g|^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\right)^2$$
Another result for $L^p$,$0<p<1$ is that it has no non-zero continuous linear functional, so people rarely use them in analysis.

Comment: But neither $f$ nor $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @ShanLinHuang I've slightly edited your answer because we deal with continuous functions

Comment: @Norbert: this is simplier,thanks